# Error while using CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE macro

Tags: c++, cppunit

After reading through the CppUnit cookbook and a lot of googling, I haven't been able to figure out the reason for the particular error I am getting.

I have a very basic CppUnit testFixture class -> 
I have a file - MyTest.h with nothing but a TestFixture class definition.

```
// MyTest.h
#include <cppunit/ui/text/TestRunner.h>
#include <cppunit/extensions/TestFactoryRegistry.h>
#include <cppunit/extensions/HelperMacros.h>

class MyTest : public CppUnit::TestFixture
{
     CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE(MyTest);    // Line num 8
     CPPUNIT_TEST(TestFailure);
     CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_END();

  public:
    void TestFailure()
    {
        CPPUNIT_ASSERT(false);
    }
 };
```

Also, a MyTest.cpp for driving this MyTest class.

```
 // MyTest.cpp
 #include "MyTest.h"
```

Then, a file called main.cpp which will instantiate runner and run the actual testcase.

```
 // main.cpp 

 #include <cppunit/ui/text/TestRunner.h>
 #include <cppunit/extensions/TestFactoryRegistry.h>
 #include <cppunit/extensions/HelperMacros.h>

 // In my main, I define a macro ADD_TEST and do #include of file called "testList.h"
 // So my testList.h can have any number of ADD_TEST macros.
 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
      CppUnit::TextUi::TestRunner runner;

      #define ADD_TEST(_testName) \
              runner.addTest(_testName::suite());
      #include testList.h"   
      #undef ADD_TEST

      runner.run();
      return true;
  }
```

Here is my testList.h ->

```
#pragma once
#include MyTest.h

ADD_TEST(MyTest)
```

Now, this file structure works - as is in Windows setup.
In linux, I get following weird errors -

```
MyTest.h: In function 'int main(int, char**)': MyTest.h:8: error: 'main(int, char**)::MyTest' uses local type 'main(int, char**)::MyTest' 
MyTest.h:8: error: trying to instantiate 'template<class Fixture> class CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContext'
MyTest.h: In static member function 'static void main(int, char**)::MyTest::addTestsToSuite(CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContextBase&)':
MyTest.h:8: error: cannot convert 'CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContextBase' to 'int' in initialization
```

This has me completely confused. I know that the macros are being picked up because if I comment out Line num8 in MyTest.h, then "suite" undeclared error comes up.
But then is CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE etc. macros are available, then why the error?
I am compiling with -lstc++, -ldl & -lcppunit flags.

Any help appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't identified your specific issue yet, but I did identify something that you might consider.  Your ADD_TEST seems a very manual way to handle what the CppUnit test registry is designed to do for you.  The reason for calling the CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE(MyTest); macro is to register your tests with the framework so you can get to them at run time.

Consider instead a main that looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    CppUnit::TextUi::TestRunner runner;
    CppUnit::Test *test = CppUnit::TestFactoryRegistry::getRegistry().makeTest();

    runner.addTest( test );
    runner.run();
    return true;
}
```

If you want to get fancy and offer different choices for which test to run, you can select them by passing a specific test name as the parameter to getRegistry, as in `getRegistry("MyTest").makeTest();`  Obviously, this could just as easily be command line or configuration file driven, however you want to implement and control it.